# How to view results of last clamscan scan?

Tags: log, clamav

I scanned pen drive using clamscan and I closed the terminal after scanning without reading the result.

Now one of my folders on the pen drive is missing. I wanted to know if clamav deleted it.

So I want to view the last scan result.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

There is no log file by default - the output goes to stdout.

In order to have a log specify it with the `-l` option i.e. `-l clamav.log`

Answer (score 4):

simply create a file e.g. example01.txt with nautilus/file-manager
then in terminal

clamscan <-parameter> >> example01.txt

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to reply, but at the time when I posted this thread, I had already executed the clamscan command and closed th terminal. So I was looking for the way to find it after running clamscan. Your suggested way works and I will keep that in mind next time! :-)