# How can I get a ClamAV report on infected files in the terminal?

Tags: clamav

I scanned my system with CLamAV by the terminal and I wanna know what files are infected. How can I get a report for that?

I want a report on my last scan, not on the next one

Comment: Here is a previous similar question with answers: http://askubuntu.com/questions/19699/how-to-view-results-of-last-clamscan-scan

Comment: @Shmukers That doesn't help `-l clamav.log` doesn't works to me

Answer (score 3):

So try: `clamscan -l clamav.log`.

Try making the log file beforehand like https://askubuntu.com/a/220100/216048 and check your write permissions (sudo it to be sure).

What error do you get?

(I would've posted a trivial comment but I don't have permissions to do that on other posts)